# Insert link to a php page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am planning to insert a link to my another php page using jquery function, but the code doesn't work... Alternative methods such as attr() has been tried as well, but it was still the same result... Can someone pls give me advices regarding this matter? Following are my codes:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){

    $('#date').change(
       function(){

          $.ajax (
            {
              url: 'process.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: {
                item_no:2,
                movie_id: $('#movie').val(),
                movie_date: $('#date').val()
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(response){ 

                $('#showtime').empty(); 
                for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++){
                    var showtime = response[i]['showtime'];

                    $('#showtime').append("<a href='movie_seat.php?id="+showtime+"' id='seatlink'>");  
                    $('#showtime').append("<font style='margin-right:50px;'>");
                    $('#showtime').append(showtime);
                    $('#showtime').append("</font></a>");
                } // for loop
              } // function taking response
            } // block in ajax
          ); //ajax
        } // function inside change
      ); // select->date change
    } // function inside ready
  ); // document.ready
```

*Note that #showtime is the id of a  attribute

My expectations:
The value displayed should be able to work as a link that will direct the user to another php page. But apparently, it doesn't....

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I was retrieving several values from my database using AJAX request, the values were successfully retrieved. Now I am trying to make all the values displayed to link to my another php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need append all together, because if you append something like this:

```js
$('#showtime').append("<a href='movie_seat.php?id="+showtime+"' id='seatlink'>");
$('#showtime').append("<font style='margin-right:50px;'>");
$('#showtime').append(showtime);
$('#showtime').append("</font></a>");
```

That way the tags will be closed, and you html will seems like this:

```js
<a href="movie_seat.php?id={idshowtime}" id="seatlink"></a>
<font style="margin-right:50px;"></font>
showtime
```

So what you need to do is append all together, i mean tags inside tags, try this:

```js
var link = "<a href='movie_seat.php?id="+showtime+"' id='seatlink'>"
        + "<font style='margin-right:50px;'>"
        + showtime
        + "</font></a>";

$('#showtime').append(link);
```